# Why would someone create a transaction where the fee is bigger than the sum of the outputs?

Tags: attack, ordinals

At the moment I am writing this question, the network is extremely bloated with, more than 60k transaction in the mempool. Inspecting the recent transactions, I found 4 very weird examples, at least very weird for me:

- [c7147a309240b768ca12ef35d3966048966d44a0d5246667d1d6b22554cd6d58](https://mempool.space/tx/c7147a309240b768ca12ef35d3966048966d44a0d5246667d1d6b22554cd6d58)
- [d9521aa9dcc4159d2020e6c8735f46e0da6b3b4467e5d80b8262226e5407b436](https://mempool.space/tx/d9521aa9dcc4159d2020e6c8735f46e0da6b3b4467e5d80b8262226e5407b436)
- [6fd8c85ff1982d9664a016492ae502bde49b2fb56eda50b26b11c49a5f7383b4](https://mempool.space/tx/6fd8c85ff1982d9664a016492ae502bde49b2fb56eda50b26b11c49a5f7383b4)
- [2997928c120e2b218ab14356271202433f9431f2d6653627c9bf86dfda0a7459](https://mempool.space/tx/2997928c120e2b218ab14356271202433f9431f2d6653627c9bf86dfda0a7459)

All these transactions have more fees than what they are sending as output to the receivers, unless I am interpreting it wrongly.

Why would someone do something like that? I can't think of any reasonable non-malicious reason for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is those are Ordinals Inscriptions (NFTs). They typically have a single output of 10000 Satoshi (about $28 US).

Update: Yes, typical huge witness data in one I checked. So fee correspondingly higher. Some ordinals are small though.

Comment: If you tie an inscription (NFT) with a small output, like 10000 satoshi, wouldn't it be a problem to transfer/sell the NFT to another address later on, because you need to pay the transaction fee? Are you essentially limiting how many times one can transfer the incription?

Comment: @Delorean, You should ask that as a [New Question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)